# Differentiation of the function $\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\ln(t)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have to differentiate with respect to x:

$$\operatorname{li}(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{\ln(t)} $$

I havn't come across this before, so my idea is to integrate it first? (Backward right?).

let $$\ln(t) = x$$

on differentiation with respect to t

$$\frac{1}{t} = \frac{dx}{dt} \implies dt = dx\cdot t$$

I would continue my attempt but it gets so messy i just don't see an end to it. Could someone shed some light on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that if $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Thus, the derivative of $$\int_2^x\dfrac{dt}{\ln t}$$ is $$\dfrac 1{\ln x}$$.

Comment: Typo: $ \frac{1}{\ln x}$

Comment: Thanks, this is the greatest thing i've learned all day. :)